# Unknown Projects in Diaolgflow

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es, project, agent

I am creating a new agent in Dialogflow, and was asked if i wanted to create a new project or add to an existing project. Two projects were listed that I do not recognize.

I went into my Firebase console and do not see the projects. Any suggestions on where I can find these mystery projects and what I set them up for originally?

Comment: You might be part of a group for that project with a viewer/editor role. Please check in the IAM console: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=<THE_PROJECT_ID_HERE> if you have this address there. If it's not you can filter by group and check there. However, there is also ongoing discussion about similar issue but not sure if this is the same topic: https://b.corp.google.com/issues/191214686

Comment: thank you, the console.cloud.google.com link worked

Answer (score 0):

Posting the answer as OP confirmed in the comment section that it resolves issue.

> thank you, the console.cloud.google.com link worked

One of the reasons why you are able to see different/3rd party projects in your account dashboard is because you were granted access to those projects as a `viewer` or `editor` role.

It can be checked in [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/) which is reachable using [this link](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project) to project `IAM Dashboard`.

Another possibility is being part of the specific group, which have `viewer/editor` role to other projects, it can be visible by filtering by group.